# How to remove code in html by JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website using Wordpress. When i viewsourge my Homepage (static page), it have code in  tag:

`<a href="link">text</a>`

Code is not have class or id, so i do not know how to remove it by JS or Jquery

How can i remove it by using JS or Jquery.

I really thank for your help

Comment: $('a href="http://tienichaz.com/danh-muc/do-tien-ich-du-lich/balo-du-lich"]').remove();   is not work

Comment: `$('a[href="link"]').remove();` or `jQuery('a[href="link"]').remove();`

Comment: @tientruong0810 You forgot the brackets around the href.

Comment: <script>
$('a[href="http://tienichaz.com/danh-muc/do-tien-ich-du-lich/balo-du-lich"]').remove();
</script> still not work, please check my code. I really thank you

Comment: Please check my website: virus [.] dlm [.] vn . I add your code, but it do not work. i need remove link tienichaz [.] com

Comment: Seems to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/0nhbae9s/) ..?

Comment: I add a test code <a href="test">test</a> in post or page wordpress, it work with your code, but i do not know why it not work with code hacker add my site

Comment: Then you've much more serious problem at hands. Removing the link at the client-side is not a solution, you've to trace how the hacker added the link, and fix the vulnerable code.

Comment: I really thanks for your help. I think i need built a new theme TT

Answer (score 0):

$('a').remove(); //if you use this, it'll remove all a from page.

**$('parentdiv a').remove();** //remove the a from that parent div

Comment: I add a test code <a href="test">test</a> in post or page wordpress, it work with your code, but i do not know why it not work with code hacker add my site

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine with jquery `remove()`,

```js
$('a[href="https://tienichaz.com/danh-muc/do-tien-ich-du-lich/balo-du-lich"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://tienichaz.com/danh-muc/do-tien-ich-du-lich/balo-du-lich">text</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: I really thanks for your help. But it is not work. I add Jquery and your code.Please check my website: virus[.]dlm[.]vn , i need remove domain: tienichaz[.]com

Comment: I add a test code <a href="test">test</a> in post or page wordpress, it work with your code, but i do not know why it not work with code hacker add my site

Answer (score 0):

You can depend on the [href] attribute of the (a) element to remove a specific (a) element
 with this jquery code:
$("a[href='the-href-value-of-the-element-you-want-to-remove']").remove();